# Renew expired fastlane certificate from .cer file. File does not contain private key

Tags: ios, keychain, fastlane, codesign, fastlane-match

I have a problem replacing our expired certificate for our project. We develop an app for a company, and i have been given a .cer file from them, to renew the certificate. However the file does not contain a key when added to the keychain, and therefore i cannot get the .p12 file that i need, to add it to fastlane. I do not have access to create new certificates.

I have tried using match import, but as this requires the .p12 file, i am a bit stuck at this point.

Is the issue due to the .cer file to not being created correctly on their end, or do I have to revoke everything, and create a new key and certificate, as i dont have access to the original private key?

Does anyone know the best solution around this?